# What is the difference between interactive rebase and normal rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

What is the different between interactive rebase, like:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

And rebase without `-i`:

```
git rebase HEAD~3
```

Comment: If you try `git rebase --help` and read through the docs, there’s some great examples of why and how to use it.

Comment: One is interactive, the other is not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Thomas Edwards commented, the docs are helpful here. As is the [pro git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) (specifically the sections on [rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) and [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

At it's core, a rebase will check out a root commit and apply a series of commits one by one.

When you do a regular rebase (`git rebase HEAD~3`), this happens automatically.

When you do an interactive rebase however (`git rebase -i HEAD~3`), you get a chance to edit the commits.

This can look like amending the commit message, squashing commits together, editing the changes in a commit or even removing commits entirely!

Comment: There are some other differences as well. If rebase is interactive, it ignores merge strategy flags.

Answer (score 3):

- Normal Rebase: Current branch is simply rebase. No feedback taken from the user
- Interactive Rebase: User has an option to play around with the commits in the current branch. User can re-order commits and other options shown below:

Commands:

- p, pick = use commit
- r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
- e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
- s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
- f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
- x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
- d, drop = remove commit

Answer (score 2):

> `Normal Rebase`

It does not take any user input so it picks all the commit from the branch without any amendment and applies all of it.

> `Interactive Rebase`

It opens the editor in front of you so that we can do any kind of amendment for each commits in whatever way we want. Like given below

> Interactive Rebase Commit Editor

```
pick <commit_hash> <commit_message>
pick 42522f0 add stack implementation

# Rebase 6aa416b..42522f0 onto 6aa416b (1 command)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick <commit> = use commit
# r, reword <commit> = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit <commit> = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash <commit> = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup <commit> = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec <command> = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# b, break = stop here (continue rebase later with 'git rebase --continue')
# d, drop <commit> = remove commit
# l, label <label> = label current HEAD with a name
# t, reset <label> = reset HEAD to a label
# m, merge [-C <commit> | -c <commit>] <label> [# <oneline>]
# .       create a merge commit using the original merge commit's
# .       message (or the oneline, if no original merge commit was
# .       specified). Use -c <commit> to reword the commit message.
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
```

**In normal rebase it get done automatically and it by default pick all of the commits rather than any amendments (rebase, edit or remove etc.)**

If you have a single commit its better to use `normal rebase` and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The interactive rebase will open an editor with a list of the commits which are about to be changed. This list accepts commands, allowing the user to edit the list before initiating the rebase action.